# @ComputedFrom throws "Cannot set property 'dependencies' of undefined"

Tags: aurelia

I am trying to return initial number minus total array length, but i am getting an error. I tried with a simple single number but my problem still persists.

I don't understand what this error means:

```
"Cannot set property 'dependencies' of undefined"
```

What are the 'dependencies'?

[image: Computed From Implementation Error]

Answer (score 11):

the error you get is because `@computedFrom` should be used on properties, and not on functions.

change

```
getpersonListCount()
{
}
```

to

```
get personListCount()
{
}
```

Comment: And note that on the view side, `personListCount` should be used instead of `getpersonListCount()`.